Julia: Flattening array of `String`s
This is essentially the same question as
Julia: Flattening array of array/tuples
but for array of Strings.  The Iterators.flatten(xs) solution shown in the above thread is excellent for numbers. But, with Strings, Iterators.flatten() flattens a String into characters!
julia> f(xs...) = collect(Iterators.flatten(xs))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f("oh", ["a", "b"], "uh")
6-element Vector{Any}:
 'o': ASCII/Unicode U+006F (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'h': ASCII/Unicode U+0068 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 "a"
 "b"
 'u': ASCII/Unicode U+0075 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'h': ASCII/Unicode U+0068 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)

How do you get an Array of Strings
"oh"
"a"
"b"
"uh"

from the above call to f()?
It would be nice if you can tell the iterator to regard String as scalar.

Instead of collect, pass the output of flatten to a list comprehension:
f( xs... ) = [ string(i) for i in Iterators.flatten( xs ) ]


Sorry that my initial question was ambiguous.  I've just rewritten it.  Yours is one solution to my original ambiguous question.
